# How to control mjpeg compression quality in ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg, image-compression

Is there a way to define the "quality/amount" of compression in ffmpeg with the mjpeg codec? Like `-crf` can be used with videos.

i.e. (mjpeg codec)

`ffmpeg -i input.jpg output.jpg`

produces a well compressed image, although it is slightly *too* compressed, what parameters can be tweaked to perform less/"better" compression?

Is there a better tool or library than ffmpeg?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [ImageMagick](https://imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php) like this:

```
magick input.jpg -quality 82 result.jpg
```

You can also control the [chroma sub-sampling](https://imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#sampling-factor) if you really want to. Check the actual quality with:

```
magick identify -verbose image.jpg      # or, more specifically
magick identify -format %Q  image.jpg
```